# Cloned Profile can't create Cases, despite identical permissions

Tags: case, permissions, profile, case-object

I cloned one of our existing profiles. With the cloning, the new profile can't cases. It receives the error:

```
We couldn't find the record you're trying to access. It may have been deleted by another user, or there may have been a system error. Ask your administrator for help.
The case still gets created.
```

Permissions between the profiles are identical. I am not using Lightning. 
Is there some other setting I don't know about?

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: There is a lot of missing info. Do you have any custom code involved in the case creation?

Comment: Not custom code, no, but it is a certain community page. It's funny because the case object actually gets CREATED, they just can't see the page where it gets created. Now that Im' thinking about it, I wonder if they don't have access to the page where they can view the created case, but they do have permissions do the Case object itself. Do you know where the permissions to that visualforce page would be shown? Adding a screenshot to the case of what the error looks like for them so that you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: you didn't mention what kind of community this is

Comment: it's a customer community. i actually didn't know there were multiple types of community...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a Sharing Set on the Customer Community which was causing all the problems..